# Negative testing using the PayPal REST API

Tags: rest, testing, paypal

I'm working on an integration with PayPal's REST API and I need to test error conditions. PayPal calls this "negative testing" and this link describes how it works for their "Classic API":

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/

I can't find any info on how this works in their REST API.  Surely they can't expect us to develop client code without testing for errors, can they?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 2 years later, they still seem not to have any support for negative testing in their rest api :(

Comment: Yup.  And what testing you can do is rendered relatively useless by #1 intermittent ISEs and #2 the fact that they run a completely different version of their software in their sandbox compared to the live site.